# Difference between broadcast , broadcast_to and broadcast_for in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

From the [Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) I found following three code snippets

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat_#{params[:room]}", data)
```

This simple broadcast sends the data to a specific chat room

while `broadcast_to` as shown below seems to send data to all chatrooms within a channel to which current user is subscribed .

```
WebNotificationsChannel.broadcast_to(
  current_user,
  title: 'New things!',
  body: 'All the news fit to print'
)
```

Here is another type of broadcast [broadcast_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Broadcasting.html) - for which i couldn't get  any example .

My question is what is actual difference between these three and when to use each of 'em - thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

`broadcasting_for` returns an object that can be reused.  This is useful for sending multiple messages to the same room in different points in code / time.  `broadcast` ends up calling `broadcasting_for`, so it's basically the same.

`broadcast_to` comes off the channel class.  You use this after you've created a channel.  Let's say you want to notify all the subscribers of blog post comments.  Then your channel would look like the example:

```
class CommentsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    stream_for post
  end
end
# use CommentsChannel.broadcast_to(@post, @comment)
```

But if you wanted to send more directed messages to a particular user then you could have a class called `EmailNotifications` that only cares about a particular user.

```
class EmailNotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  ...

EmailNotificationsChannel.broadcast_to(
  current_user,
  title: 'You have mail!',
  body: data[:email_preview]   # some assumption of passed in or existing data hash here
)
```